What is the name of this cartoon?
I'm watching this cartoon(dubbed) on local TV channel and it is really funny. Does anyone know it's original name? 


@Ankit Sharma It's unfair to mark this as duplicate as I already searched this image in Google images and pound no answer. I'm hoping some help from this community if someone know the answer. I'm looking for this specific image, not a general answer.

There is nothing unfair or personal, it's just the quality standardization.

@Ankit Sharma If you tried Google image search this image it will not show the answer that I'm looking for. It only shows the local web site images.

It giving result as Chuttai Chutti Sinhala Cartoon even with videos from some video link which i can't access right now.

@AnkitSharma Yeah, that's why I called it local web site. That is not the original. The original may be English or any other language without Sinhala.

But that doesn't qualify it as a good ID question. Image only identification questions are not on topic here.

The original name of this cartoon is "Les P'tits Diables". 
It is a French Cartoon adapted from French comic.
credit: @IdiotStyle

Awesome, that's it Les ptit's diables

Is it @IdiotStyle or pardyot?
